# Sending raw post data

Tags: php, html

How would I send raw post data and in the receiving .php use file_get_contents('php://input')... How would I setup the form to do this?

So basically file_get_contents reads in the file as a string from php input?

Answer (score 0):

In the action of the form set the page to `wibble.php` then in `wibble.php` write

```
<?PHP
file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

Comment: What if the page that it's posting to isn't the same page?

Comment: If we post to the same page, are all input fields considered in "php://input".

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the php.ini directive [always_populate_raw_post_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data).

php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".